# Find the lengths of the given curves

Tags: calculus, algebraic-curves

I have a problem where I need to find the length of a given curve using integration. I've probably put about $2$ whole hours into this question, but I'm completely stumped as to solving it. Here's the question:

> Find the arc length of $y = \dfrac32~x^{2/3}$ on the interval $1\le x\le8$.

I know to set up an integral on the bounds from $1$ to $8$, and write it as $1+\big(dy/dx\big)^2$ under a root, if that makes sense. I end up with the integral of $\sqrt{1 + x^{-2/3}}$ . I've tried everything I know of, but I simply cannot figure out how to process this integral. Can anybody offer an advice to solving this? Sorry if my formatting is bad, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equals $x^{-1/3}\sqrt{x^{2/3}+1}$, so use the substitution $u=x^{2/3}$.

Comment: I hadn't thought about taking that x^-1/3 out from the integrand. Thanks a bunch!!